# How to call azure graph api using postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to call graph api to get user information. I am using postman to get the token first and then using that token trying to make a request to graph api

I get the token with below post request and with 4 key values for `grant_type, client_id, client_secret and resource.`

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantid}}/oauth2/token
```

The response is

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1555583717",
    "not_before": "1555579817",
    "resource": "https://management.azure.com/",
    "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxNiIsIng1dCI6IkhCeGw5bUFlNmd4YXZDa2NvT1UyVEhzRE5hMCIsImtpZCI6IkhCeGw5bUFlNmd4YXZDa2NvT1UyVEhzRE5hMCJ9.yyyyyyyLTBjYjZmZDNiM2UwNCIsInRpZCI6IjM3NGY4MDI2LTdiNTQtNGEzYS1iODdkLTMyOGZhMjZlYzEwZCIsInV0aSI6ImVWTWdDbkU4QWtPVXY3bFQ2QlRSQUEiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxLjAifQ.kxHCm2oGsuUvlXbncXQe7Wb0l-ZENqqG9_P_co0SPdYA3GkhFKDi6sQ7OaaHeDs4S6kN0-Diw5qBOzmFipSA5EUorA7UDbJfiSVVlaEzLY3IX_4WSV4Exc-kLOaX0j7KgvsEQbc5TEk8e4dPfokG98gGPmhy19xLyV84lX1v6DzgXINzP8gPkGmqR_J7iVFQ3m-Y18dHlxDpqQMTKxvQGnrsa7rflyxGUwEwwFZJH8t5NRv_mjQOIQBuosfhMAH88l-J8zEmXWLFqEzFBBWrz9UxT6X-XxRQZW4WBSoHTKd3vuBcEo6kUclfe4G7COOvI4zG0-j10mmGziKlzjNVMw"
}
```

Then I use the token to make GET request

```
https://graph.windows.net/{{company}}/users/{{email}}?api-version=1.6
```

and header

```
Key                     Value
Authorization         Bearer {{token}}
```

but it fails with this error

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to make a request to graph api ?

Comment: I think when you get the oauth2 token, it is not just the access_token, but a more complex object with several tokens. 
It is only the access_token that needs to follow the word "Bearer". 
But I am not sure.

Comment: You are correct Dimitri :) Also, make sure your resource is `https://graph.windows.net`

Comment: I have added a response from auth but not sure what to extract from that. Can you please check?

Comment: You used the wrong resource. The token you get is for Azure Management API. You need to ask for a token for AAD Graph API by setting the resource to `https://graph.windows.net`

Comment: It says             "value": "Invalid domain name in the request url."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Updated answer according to your case***

Okay I am showing the step from the beginning. Make sure you have complete following step exactly.

***Step:1 : Application Registration***

Go to your azure portal and click on `azure active directory`. Now click on `App registrations` and Enter a name for your app. Make sure you have select `Web app / API` as application type. Put any `Sign on URL` it does not have any impact though.

See the screen shot below:

[image]

***Step:2 Application Configuration***

Configure your application setting by clicking on `settings` option. Copy the `Application Id` which is your client ID. Generate your `client_secret` on `Key` menu. Now click on `Required permission`  option and  click on `Add` at new window. Choose `Select an API` choose `Microsoft Graph` Then Select it.

See the below screen shot

[image]

So your azure portal configuration is all set.

***Step:3 Token Access Flow***

For getting token I am using [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). Let fire up `POSTMAN` Enter your token endpoint your like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/`YourTenantNameOrID`.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
```

***Enter following data in right format:***

> grant_type:client_credentials
>
> client_id:Your Portal Application ID
>
> client_secret:Your application Key
>
> resource:https://graph.microsoft.com/
>
> **Note:** I am using Microsoft Graph API so resource has chosen
>   [//graph.microsoft.com/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0#examples)

See the screen shot for more details

[image]

***Step: 4 Check Claims Of your Token***

You can make sure your token contains required information by validating it claims on JWT. You can use https://jwt.io/ to validate your token.

See the picture of claims below:

[image]

**Step:5 Access Your Microsoft Graph API Resource**

1. Define your Microsoft Graph API resource URL

> For example : [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0#examples)

2. Select your API http verb
3. Select Your Token Type to Bearer Token
4. Enter your token on left token text box

You are done click send and check your response as expected. See the screen shot for details.

***Request Format:***

[image]

***Response From API:***

***[image: Response From API]***

> **Note:** Make sure you have resource access permission unless you would get access denied error.

For more information you could take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)

If you have any more confusion feel free to ask in comment line. Thank you and Happy coding!

Comment: Tried that but the same issue. Could it be possible that delegated permissions are not sufficient?

Comment: @user1298426 Could you try now. I have updated my answer from the beginning to End. Still if you have any query feel free to ask here in comment.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't see "scp" key in my token. Does it mean I don't have permission to access api?

Comment: @user1298426 Yeah It is...so assign permission on portal the way I  explain above. do exactly what I did you would get expected result. If you still have any problem feel free to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can review the link of microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman