# AADSTS70003: The app requested an unsupported grant type 'client_credential'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am actually testing the call of Graph API from POSTMAN in order to get access to Active Directory information.

I have follow the steps mentionned in this ticket:
[How to call azure graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55742935/how-to-call-azure-graph-api-using-postman)

When posting the request in order to get my TOKEN ID as explain in the link above, then I get a return error as below :

```
 "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70003: The app requested an unsupported grant type 'client_credential'.\r\nTrace ID: 0cdad91b-0ba8-4310-92d4-f0aff8bb1d00\r\nCorrelation ID: fdf416d6-eb81-4a5c-9577-af9d9f28fab0\r\nTimestamp: 2020-04-28 13:27:04Z",
    "error_codes": [
        70003
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-04-28 13:27:04Z",
    "trace_id": "0cdad91b-0ba8-4310-92d4-f0aff8bb1d00",
    "correlation_id": "fdf416d6-eb81-4a5c-9577-af9d9f28fab0"
```

Any idea how to solve it and what could be wrong ?

regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like typo.

Please confirm **grant_type** is set to **client_credentials**