# Get List of Applications For a Specific Microsoft Azure Tenant

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication

As you know currently a user needs to access https://myapps.microsoft.com/ then select an organization and then a list of applications is displayed.

I'm trying to re-build that portal in a single JS page. The user already authenticates with Azure to reach this JS page, and my target is to make a call to microsoft and retrieve the list of applications available for this specific user.

All I found in microsoft docs is how to retrieve data and access token for a specific application using the client secret and details about this application. But in my case I don't have an application all I have is a tenant id.

Is this feasible? keep in mind I can only use JS not nodejs or angular etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below graph api to list all of the apps which the specific user be assigned a role.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/appRoleAssignments
```

[image]

The `resourceDisplayName` is the name of the app shown in the page you provided and the `resourceId` is the objectId of the app(service principal) in azure.

By the way, it seems the page you provided doesn't show all of the apps which the specific user be assigned a role. I'm not sure if there is bug in that page, but the graph api I provided shows all of the apps for the specific(the user is assigned a role in the app).

Hope it helps~

Comment: Hello Hury, thank you for your answer. This call requires a Bearer {token} for authorization. How can I retrieve this token to make this call? I don't have a client secret or app id .

Comment: @MohammadShokor You need to [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) a app in your azure ad first. And then generate client secret and add permissions to it by following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration). After that [get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) the access token according to the app you registered and use the access token to request this graph api.

Comment: @MohammadShokor By the way, you'd better to use v1.0 graph api but not the beta graph api I provided in my answer. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is the document of the v1.0 graph api.

Comment: @MohammadShokor Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55742935/how-to-call-azure-graph-api-using-postman) which may help you, it includes all of the steps to register app, generate secret, add permissions, get access token and request the graph api.

Comment: Hi @MohammadShokor May I know if your problem was solved ? If the solution helps your problem, could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~